# what is the difference between postings Format and Points Format in Lucene?

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, lucene

In Lucene 7 and 6 there is a format called PointsFormat and it uses BKD tree data Structure .and posting Format uses FST data Structure in lucene 4 for indexing.
1)i would like to know difference between this two?

2) what is the advantage of moving from one version into another one in lucene?

3)In Lucene which data structure is a efficient in indexing ?

Answer (score 0):

These format are technically and logically different. PointsFormat is using for encoding/decoding [PointValues](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/PointValues.html) (which are basically numeric values, introduced in recent versions of Lucene), while PostingsFormat is the format for encoding/decoding terms, postings, and proximity data.

Also, these format classes are abstract and there a lot of implemented format in both Lucene 6 and 7.

Answering to your following questions - moving to a newer version of Lucene is usually a plus for performance, as well as new functionality.

Both of these structures are efficient, but they are different just for storing different types of data